# Magento + gclid + redirect is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, redirect-url, querystring

I've just been on the phone with Adwords and they've told me my gclid url query string is not working properly.

So I did some digging and found this stackexchange question / answer that really looks like it should solve my problems:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629722/magento-category-redirect-cuts-off-the-querystring-of-an-url

The thing is, the answer says to put the following code in Request.php

```
    $queryString = $this->_getQueryString();
    if ($queryString) {
        $targetUrl .= '?'.$queryString;
    }
```

When I look in Request.php - that code is already there (magento 1.9.0.1) - but when I make a request on a URL with a query string to a page that is redirected by magento (such as one of my top menu pages), no query string is appended to the redirected to url.

Can someone please help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you flush cache afterwards?